# launch cmd run command isn't working

Tags: command, exit, execute, cmd

I am working on a script or batch file (or combo of the two) which imports an outlook prf file, then launches a new cmd.exe window runs a application specific program which when passed a server cluster name pulls in an outlook data file in the previously created outlook profile. So i have the vbs script that checks for the outlook profile if it doesn't exist it imports the prf. That's working fine, now the program i need to is called addiman.exe the server cluster name is gsiapp...the manual method is i launch a cmd windows and type "addiman gsiapp" i wish to automates this by calling it in a routine called :Filesite the below command has been unsuccessful, it launches a new cmd.exe window but doesn't run the command.

```
:ImportPRf

call cscript \\gsf1\Apps\Scripts\public\deployprf.vbs

GOTO :FileSite

:FileSite

start cmd.exe /c "c:\program files\interwoven\worksite\addiman.exe" GSIAPP

GOTO :EXIT

:Exit
Exit
```

Comment: first off batch reads the file in order so the GOTO :filesite and the :filesite are considered indexes so it could run without the :filesite section also Call is not for starting Cscript files call is to call another batch file. so you can replace it with start. best if you stick with one or the other so VBS or Batch.

Comment: try doing CMD "file path" command prompt automatically starts a new CMD window when cmd is passed as a command

Answer (score 1):

```
start cmd.exe /c "c:\program files\interwoven\worksite\addiman.exe GSIAPP"
```

try this, because cmd.exe interprets the part between "" as comand and ignores the GSIAPP statement

Answer (score 0):

wild guess. Try adding another call before the "start" - like this

```
:FileSite

call start cmd.exe /c "c:\program files\interwoven\worksite\addiman.exe" GSIAPP
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, unfortunately it did not work :(

Comment: i paid a bit closer attention and also the /c was causing command prompt to close preventing me from seeing it, i used a /k  and i see what is occuring now but don't know the proper syntax, the start cmd.exe is working but in the new window at the top it reads.. "'c:\Proram' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. So it's not seeing the quotations around the full path to the addiman.exe program. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

problem solved, the full path isn't needed. just had to putt "addiman GSIAPP". Thanks everyone who provided suggestions.